# How to find what color my roofing is?

Tags: roof, roofing

I'm looking to replace my roof and the company gave me a few color options. I can't tell right now what color my roof is or what color mostly matches. Is there a definite way to figure this out myself? If anyone of your are pros, can you tell by a photo?

Comment: Are we talking about asphalt shingles?

Comment: Most experienced roofers can tell just by looking what brand/color shingle is on your roof. Whether that color/brand/style shingle is still being made is another question. You can probably find a better shingle with a very similar color to replace what you have. The issue is your roofer may only install GAF another Owens Corning and others may install an inferior brand. Some roofers may only carry samples of one brand so as with most projects get multiple bids and one of the roofers should have a color that satisfies  you.

Comment: As the last bit of Isherwood's answer says, if you are replacing the WHOLE roof, there is **absolutely no need or benefit** to precisely matching the color you have. As it does not say, if you are only replacing part of the roof, there may still not be a match due to "new" .vs. "aged" color of "the same" shingles, as well as any lot-to-lot variations (which is why they put lot numbers on the shingle packages.) Having saved the extra shingles, I've seen the difference between shingles on the roof for 10 years and shingles stored inside for 10 years that were literally from the same package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photos can help, but shingle lots vary even within the same brand and color. Your best bet is to remove a shingle and look for a brand. Once you have that there's probably only one color that's an obvious match.

Either look up manufacturer websites or visit a store with a wide range of offerings and do a direct comparison. Keep in mind that age and normal variation may result in differences.

That said, do you really want the exact same color for another 20 years? Now's your chance to make a pleasing change, even if small.